# import android.support cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm getting an error stating: import android.support cannot be resolved at the line:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Has anyone seen this before or have any idea what I can do to resolve it? The issue occurs when adding a library I've built - and goes away when I remove it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right click the `project properties->java build path->libraries click add external jar`.

browse go to android installation folder like `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4` there you find the `android_support_v4.jar`  file then add the jar file and go to order and export tab check the library and click ok..

Comment: There is no project properties in Android Studio. Do not lie please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `android-support-v4.jar` to your project. It looks like your library requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a dependecy to the Support Library.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html on how to add the dependency in your IDE.