# I can't use Notification

Tags: java, android, sdk, netbeans-6.9

i'm developing a software and i need to create a notification.. Well seeing a lot tutorial, i can't follow one, because my import NotificationCompat don't show.

[image: NotificationError]

I updated ALL my SKD Manager and I did jar download (android-support-v4.jar), don't work

[image: SDK Android]

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          //Notification Here!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Right click the project properties->java build path->libraries click add external jar.

browse go to android installation folder like C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4 there you find the android_support_v4.jar file then add the jar file and go to order and export tab check the library and click ok.."

Font: [import android.support cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856264/import-android-support-cannot-be-resolved)